# How to center text in xfce desktop?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I just installed [Flatabulous](https://github.com/anmoljagetia/Flatabulous) (a theme) on my computer that runs Xubuntu.

This happened on my desktop:

[image: desktop]

It seems that the icon text is left-aligned.

I tried looking around `/usr/share/themes/Flatabulous/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` like others have suggested, but I couldn't find any styles that concerned the icon alignment.

From the [xfce docs](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfdesktop/advanced), it says:

> ## Hidden Xfconf Options
>
> There are a couple of hidden xfconf settings that cannot be set by the xfdesktop-settings application. The channel name that xfdesktop uses is 'xfce4-desktop'. For more information see the Xfconf Documentation.
>
> …
>
> /desktop-icons/center-text
>
> - Boolean, default is TRUE.
> - This value controls whether the text for all the desktop icons label are centered.

I believe this is the correct setting, but I couldn't find it anywhere. It says it should be in `xfdesktop-settings` (the "Desktop" application), but it's not there. Any tips?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the quote you provided, it seems that the setting `/desktop-icons/center-text` should *not* be in `xfdesktop-settings`. Instead, it must be accessed via  `xfconf-query`.

Strangely, it seems that the property `/desktop-icons/center-text` must be set to `false` in order to work properly with Flatabulous. This property does not seem to be created by default. In order to make it and set it to `false`, you can do the following:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /desktop-icons/center-text -n -t bool -s false
```

You should see the change immediately, but you can log off or reboot if it is not showing up.

Comment: It worked with `false` at the end, not `true`. I think you just made a typo there. Thanks!

Comment: Will this change persist? Will I have to set this setting every time I login?

Comment: @JonathanLam Thanks for catching the typo. The effect should persist.