# Items names incorrectly displayed on desktop (Xubuntu 16.04)

Tags: xubuntu, icons, xfce

recently I noticed that the names of elements on my desktop on Xubuntu 16.04 are displaying incorrectly. I didn't mess with any XFCE settings or anything. Just after some update they broke. Here you can see what's wrong:

[image]

The text shadow in where it should be, but the name itself if behaving like it has "text-align: left" applied to it. In case of elements with longer names, this effect is less visible.

Any ideas how can I fix this?

Comment: Could be related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/801460/how-to-center-text-in-xfce-desktop.

Comment: The solution from the question you linked to worked! Thanks!