# Xubuntu 16.04 window headings ugly

Tags: 16.04, themes, appearance

I just installed Xubuntu 16.04 and tried implementing some different themes from gnome-look. Alas, there seems to be something fishy going on with the window heads (or whatever you call the topmost part of the windows). Here's a picture of how my windows look:

[image: picture]

As can be seen both the file manager and chromium windows look ugly, while, for some reason, the theme seems to work for the software centre window. I'm using the Arc dark Red theme. I've tried with different themes and the ugly windows seem to persist, at least for dark themes.

Comment: The white texts of the icons on your desktop are also off-center. To fix this, try http://askubuntu.com/questions/801460/how-to-center-text-in-xfce-desktop. I am not sure if this will help with the window headings though.

Comment: That's great, at least one problem gone! Still more annoyed by the headings though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:

Since the ppa below is now obsolete, this is no longer the way to get xfce-theme-manager. However, as noted by @linuxmarc here: [I cannot download xfce theme manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112263/i-cannot-download-xfce-theme-manager), it is still possible to get the software here: https://github.com/KeithDHedger/Xfce-Theme-Manager/releases. Installation instructions are provided in the README therein.

---

I solved the problem after spending more hours then I'm comfortable admitting.

Installing xfce theme manager and applying the theme with that worked like a charm. It can be installed with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rebuntu16/other-stuff 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xfce-theme-manager
```

Source: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/xfce-theme-manager-single-gui-to-change.html