# I cannot download xfce theme manager

Tags: themes, xfce, xfwm4

On my xubuntu I have this horrible software heading:

[image: Titlebar in Xubuntu]

I want to remove it. A post said to download xfce-theme-manager, so I did everything I had to do:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rebuntu16/other-stuff`
2. `sudo apt update`
3. `sudo apt-get install xfce-theme-manager`

When I try to install xfce theme manager I get an error along the lines of `xfce-theme-manager doesn't exist` *(My language is Italian, so I don't know the exact translation)*

Detail: I use gtk themes

What can I do to install xfce-theme-manager or at least, not having those software headings anymore?

Comment: Please post an image of "software headings".

Comment: @DKBose [headings](https://len.meek.moe/Istantanea_2019-01-06_20-58-46.png)

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you want to change the theme of your window manager. For that, you do not have to install any extra software.

Click on the mouse icon (or the menu icon) usually located at the left end of your panel). In the window that opens, click on *Settings* in the *right* pane and then scroll down to window manager in the *left* pane.

[image: Menu > Settings > Window Manager]

You'll get a new window titled *Window Manager*. Click on the *Style* tab. The "software heading" will change depending on the theme you choose in the *left* pane. You can make other changes there as well. In the next image, I've chosen Numix.

[image: Selecting a different theme for the window manager]

And this is what the Greybird theme looks like (and it resembles the image you posted):

[image: Greybird]

Answer (score 1):

Get it here:
https://github.com/KeithDHedger/Xfce-Theme-Manager/releases

Unpack, then
cd into the folder and execute following commands:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

et voila, you have the XFCE Theme manager in your menu